# How to intercept RavenDb Session.SaveChanges()

Tags: ravendb

I am looking for a way to intercept `Session.SaveChanges()` so that I may execute some extra work using the same session instance (this is handy in some cases).

**Edit:** The point about re-using the session is that I have more work that needs to run in the *same transaction*.

I am already aware of (and make use of) `IDocumentStoreListener` - but this interface doesn't help because it does not give me access to the current session.

I can't find anything in RavenDb documentation about a way to intercept the call to SaveChanges and get a handle on the current session. Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: Is this for a web app? Typically, for MVC and Web API apps, you create a document session per OWIN context.

Comment: It needs to work both in a web app and in webjobs (or any other context). We've moved away from using one session per request as it brings with it more problems than it solves.

I have a solution in mind, now, but haven't had the time to implement it. Will post again when I've done it

Comment: I'm curious to hear what problems you have with having a session per request. I've built numerous web apps (some enterprise-scale) using a session per request, and it's worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new session it's free (in terms of performance), I think that *IDocumentStoreListener* has been thought for what you're looking for. I don't know other that works as you say.

implementing
`void AfterStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata);`
you have all the information about the stored entity and then you can do what you need

Comment: Opening a new session is indeed 'free', but it's not what I need. I need to do more work in the same transaction. I've updated the question to be clear about this. Oren suggests using CallContext for stashing the session (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/bXeUJ3qVBpQ) and I'm looking into that. I'm unsure if session can be stashed in CallContext, though, as it might be serialized.

Comment: @Øyvind it's a work around, but: what if you use the before store to do what you need and if something fails you can return false or throw an exception

Comment: the problem remains: how to get your hands on the _current_ session. Opening a new one is easy, but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Øyvind i said that it's a work around. Extend the functionality of raven creating your own layer